# Choose primary key

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a table to track income and outcome. I have the following rows

- type [can assume 3 values]
- date [date of the transaction]
- incomeAmout
- incomeDescription
- outcomeAmount
- outcomeDescription

If I have date as primary then I won't be able to have multiple transaction in the same date. I could make all the rows as primary key but I'm not sure this is the best way to proceed. What would you suggest me to do? I read some topics about creating an auto incremental index but I'm wondering if I can make it without adding another attribute.
Thanks

Comment: Even if you use all your attributes, they're still not unique. So you need a key.

Answer (score 0):

Make an `id` column as a primary key. This will be your immutable record identifier.

You'll probably want to have some kind of randomized transaction identifier as well, something like a UUID or a value derived from the SHA256 hash of something. That way you can share these identifiers without revealing too much about your database structure or how many records there are in the database.

Then, if you need another key, add it as a `UNIQUE` index, or define whatever unique constraints you want to enforce as a compound key.

Answer (score 0):

Your question should be: [Surrogate Key vs. Natural Key](http://sqlmag.com/business-intelligence/surrogate-key-vs-natural-key)

In your case, you have no choice but to use Surrogate Key: create a new field named "ID" and set it as Integer, Autoincrement, Primary Key.

BTW, Microsoft recommends use of Surrogate key as a good practice.